# How to compare two ipv6 addresses on a little endian machine in C

Tags: c

I am trying to compare two ipv6 addresses however want to create the code to be portable. I know that ipv6 addresses are stored in network byte order (big endian) so on a big-endian CPU I can simply use memcmp across the two in6_addr structs. But what is the easiest way to do the same thing on a little-endian machine?

[EDIT] When I want to compare two addresses I want to figure out whether an address is less, equal, or greater than the other. I thought memcmp would be endian dependent in the order it scans across bits in memory.

Comment: If both addresses are in network byte order you can just `memcmp()` them.

Comment: Why do you think the same `memcmp()` wouldn't work on a little-endian machine?

Comment: `memcmp()` should still help in this case, mostly because its in network byte order, it just make things perfect to compare byte per byte. `memcmp()` will return `< 0` if the first address specified comes before the other, `0` if they are identical, and `> 0` if it comes after the other.

Comment: Socket functions will always require network byte order for the foreseeable future, both when sending and receiving data. The only time you need to worry about the byte order is when you need to use the IP address on your local machine, e.g. displaying it as a part of a log file, error message, etc.; that is when you'd need to convert network byte order to host byte order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think memcmp will probably work.  There's not a popular machine with a 128-bit data type that I know of.  I suspect ipv6 address are usually carried around as arrays of bytes.  Given that network byte order is big-endian, memcmp will see and compare the high-order byte first, as you want it to.

You were right to have wondered if the machine's endianness matters for portability, but in this case, I think it doesn't.  Endianness matters when we're working with 16- or 32-bit integers that have been copied off the network, and we want to work with them as integers.  But here, with just an array of bytes, that concern does not exist.

I don't usually say this -- I usually like to understand for sure what I'm doing first -- but, try it and see!